# How to Upload images from local folder to Sitecore

Tags: web, sitecore, sitecore6

`webClient.UploadFile("http://www.myurl.com/~/media/DCF92BB74CDA4D558EEF2D3C30216E30.ashx", @"E:\filesImage\Item.png");
I'm trying to upload images to sitecore using webclient.uploadfile() method by sending my sitecore address and the path of my local images.But I'm not able to upload it.I have to do this without any API's and Sitecore Instances.

Comment: Srinu, one of your other comments includes some restrictions you have. I would recommend adding those restrictions to your question to ensure you get better answers that can help you in your particular situation.

Comment: I have no idea about those restrictions

Comment: You state below: "I'm not using Sitecore Namespaces and media items. I have to do it through Xml "
and also:
"how to do using WebClient".
These are restrictions on how what options are available to you.

Comment: @Srinu Be careful to anonymize what you post on here. I now know who your client is and have just been able to guess the location of the login page. At least admin/b has been changed ;)

Answer (score 1):

The upload process would be the [same as with any ASP.net application](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_file_uploading.htm). However, once the file has been uploaded you need to create a media item programtically. You can do this from an actual file in the file system, or from a memory stream.

The process involves using a `MediaCreator` object and using its `CreateFromFile` method.

This blog post outlines the whole process:
[Adding a file to the Sitecore Media Library programatically](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/adding-a-file-to-the-sitecore-media-library-programatically/)

Comment: I'm not using Sitecore Namespaces and media items. I have to do it through Xml

Comment: I assume you mean you want enter the data directly in to the database. I don't know how to do this, I also wouldn't advise trying.

Comment: U might be correct but I have to do so. Can you help me how to do using WebClient

Comment: How can i access Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions. @Martin Davies

Comment: The blog referenced in the answer explains this. `var options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions();`

Comment: I don have this dll "Sitecore.Resources.Media "

Comment: It's in the Sitecore.Kernel dll

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking simply about optimizing your developer workflow you could use the [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) using the Remoting API as described in this [this blog post](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/10/sitecore-powershell-extensions-remoting/)

Comment: I want to Upload Images to Sitecore via WebClient call

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use web service way than you can use number of ways which are as follows:
a) Sitecore Rocks WebService (If you are allowed to install that or it is already available).
b) Sitecore Razl Service(It is third party which need license).
c) [Sitecore Powershell Remoting](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/10/sitecore-powershell-extensions-remoting/) (This needs Sitecore PowerShell extensions to be installed on Sitecore Server).
d) You can also use Sitecore Service which you can find under sitecore\shell\WebService\Service.asmx (But this is legacy of new SitecoreItemWebAPI)
e) [Last is my enhanced SitecoreItemWebAPI](https://github.com/vishalniit/SitecoreItemWebAPI-CoreSync1.0) (This also need SitecoreItemWebApi 1.2 as a pre-requisite).

But in end except option d you need to install some or other thing in order to upload the image using HTTP, you should also know the valid credentials to use any of above stated methods.

Comment: How can I access "Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions" class

Comment: Hi Srinu, It is a type you can find in Sitecore.Kernel .dll file and as martin said above you can use that post from brian to create media item.

Comment: May I know what is meant by MediaItem

Comment: Sorry Srinu, but it looks like you lack basic terminology in sitecore, In Sitecore we store images/pdf/docs as MediaItem. They are also Sitecore item but an Item which can store the blob as value. If you are not sure of this basic thing I am not sure how you get to this problem..

Answer (score 0):

If your customers upload the image on the website, you need to create the item in your master database. (needs access and write right on the master database) depend on your security you might consider not build it with custom code.

But using the Sitecore webforms for marketers module With out of the box file upload. Create a form with upload field and using the WFFM webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Option: You can use Item Web API for it. No reference to any Sitecore dll is needed. You will only need access to the host and be able to enable the Item Web API.

References: 
Upload the files using it: http://www.sitecoreinsight.com/how-create-media-items-using-sitecore-item-web-api/

Enable Item Web Api: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-a4.pdf#search=%22item%22

I guess that is pretty much what you need, but as Jay S mentioned, if you put more details on your question helps on finding the best option to your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use Sitecore API, then you can do the following:

1. Write a code that uploads images into this folder : **[root]/upload/**
2. You might need to create folder structure that represent how the images are stored in Sitecore, eg: your images uploaded into **[root]/upload/Import/** will be stored in **/sitecore/media library/Import**
3. Sitecore will automatically upload these images into Media library

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateImageIteminSitecore()
    {
        filePath = @"C:\Sitecore\Website\ImageTemp\Pic.jpg;
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

            Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions options = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions();
            options.FileBased = true;
            options.AlternateText = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            options.Destination = "/sitecore/media library/Downloads/";
            options.Database = masterDb;


            options.Versioned = false; // Do not make a versioned template
            options.KeepExisting = false;
            Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem mediaitemImage = new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator().CreateFromFile(filePath, options);
            Item ImageItem = masterDb.GetItem(mediaitemImage.ID.ToString());
            ImageItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            ImageItem.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            ImageItem.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
```